# a script to follow and log a php code line by line

Tags: php

i have a php code that a funny guy has been done some jokes,
the file is so ugly because there is too many `goto` operator in the code and i can't understand it,
i need to make this clean,
i need a script to run this php code line by line and export the real code,
it's just a path , the script need to follow the `goto` operator and log the clean code

take a look

```
goto pGKSW;
 pGKSW: defined("BASEPATH") or exit("No direct script access allowed");
 goto gZ8Qk;
 gZ8Qk: require dirname(__FILE__) . "/Base.php";
 goto pgTdS;
     pgTdS: class MX_Controller {
     public $autoload = array();
         public function __construct() {
         goto Vm955;
         UKFW9: $Ry8Qr = encrypt_decode($_COOKIE["verify_maintenance_mode"]);
         goto iIp0E;
         fiy7l:  goto snjE4;
             prcVs: if (!($EiHk3["role"] != "admin" && (in_array($this->router->fetch_class(), $Z9cvS) || in_array(segment(2), ["update"])))) {
             goto jpMmm;
             
        }
         goto Z0zWG;
         xsXkO: $EiHk3 = session("user_current_info");
         goto Y5Dmy;
         v0I44: ipfmS: goto K_WUN;
         fCYWZ: OfujJ: goto Uz56g;
         qOjiH: $cqcJW = $LCB3v;
         goto aGnp_;
         ES4LA: $NjUSf->db->query("DELETE FROM general_sessions WHERE timestamp < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))");
         goto fCYWZ;
         Xis9_: jccIp: goto ql7pb;
             dzO24: if (!session("uid")) {
             goto OfujJ;
             
        }
         goto hwKtZ;
         cGZGq: LRSEO: goto ES4LA;
         ql7pb: lCNNx: goto cGZGq;
         K_WUN: vEfUE: goto Xis9_;
         FyUSo: $lHaPp = $NjUSf->db->select("purchase_code")->where("pid", 23595718)->get("general_purchase")->row()->purchase_code;
         goto PI2_a;
             HxSqW: if (!($w5r4c != "verified" && segment(2) != "logout")) {
             goto LRSEO;
             
        }
         goto xLiPb;
         HAN0p: $this->load = clone load_class("Loader");
         goto lWxUL;
         Y5Dmy: $Z9cvS = $this->user_allowed_controllers($EiHk3["role"]);
         goto QIL51;
         P7Yb3: $Ry8Qr = "non-verified";
         goto deA6s;
         X0_LD: Y2nMT: goto Jmw9G;
         wPJ76: $gbjrX = array("logout");
         goto HxJFt;
         CaPDC: $LCB3v = "There is some issue with your purchase code, please contact with me via email tuyennguyen2906@gmail.com";
         goto sBAvn;
         Vm955: $oz81W = str_replace(CI::$APP->config->item("controller_suffix"), '', get_class($this));
         goto czx7C;
         hwKtZ: $Z9cvS = [];
         goto xsXkO;
         awyvW:  goto ZJgCR;
         ZJgCR: goto vEfUE;
         goto X0_LD;
         aIULL: Y9CVq: goto v0I44;
         vtb3D: jpMmm: goto HxSqW;
             xLiPb: if (!(segment(1) != "module" && $EiHk3["role"] == "admin")) {
             goto lCNNx;
             
        }
         goto FyUSo;
         czx7C: log_message("debug", $oz81W . " MX_Controller Initialized");
         goto h4wtr;
         n2U9a: date_default_timezone_set(TIMEZONE);
         goto HAN0p;
         rVYYt: cArjg: goto dzO24;
             YfFhB: switch ($R1bsw->status) {
             case "error": goto fPbra;
             fPbra: $cqcJW = base64_encode($R1bsw->message);
             goto FDu2W;
             FDu2W: redirect(PATH . "module?error=" . $cqcJW);
             goto DHV6h;
             GEeYr: goto Y9CVq;
             goto VZDyf;
             DHV6h:  goto GEeYr;
             VZDyf: case "success": goto TMdLn;
             RHjcn: set_cookie("lc_verified", base64_encode("verified"), 1209600);
             goto cJNq3;
             TMdLn: update_option("get_features_option", 1);
             goto RHjcn;
             cJNq3: goto Y9CVq;
             goto yR1QX;
             yR1QX: 
        }
         goto INGhz;
         K8te8: $cqcJW = $LCB3v;
         goto dxUfj;
             PI2_a: if (!empty($lHaPp)) {
             goto g8OFd;
             
        }
         goto vj8xp;
         WKXFM: redirect(cn("maintenance"));
         goto m7gY6;
             s7Ak9: if (!($Ry8Qr != "verified" && $this->__check_maintenance_mode() && segment(1) != "maintenance")) {
             goto G6RCC;
             
        }
         goto WKXFM;
         bLU4U: GYrf8: goto rVYYt;
         QIL51: $w5r4c = '';
         goto Si7kC;
             HOEGB: if ($sr19N != '') {
             goto Y2nMT;
             
        }
         goto K8te8;
             tuGJa: if (is_object($R1bsw)) {
             goto rezoq;
             
        }
         goto qOjiH;
             HxJFt: if (!(!session("uid") && !$this->__check_maintenance_mode() && !in_array($this->router->fetch_class(), $yBBxd) && !in_array($this->router->fetch_method(), $gbjrX))) {
             goto GYrf8;
             
        }
         goto eS3Nc;
         IYQvf: redirect(PATH . "module?error=" . $cqcJW);
         goto AOFGp;
         sOZZq: ICIk8: goto prcVs;
         lWxUL: $this->load->initialize($this);
         goto fP3bG;
         kCne5: $yBBxd = array("auth", "api", "client", "services");
         goto wPJ76;
         igRjN: redirect(PATH);
         goto gGOSL;
         iIp0E: FQtNH: goto s7Ak9;
         yHvrg: goto jccIp;
         goto YrdbT;
         j1srf: $wCbGV = "https://smartpanelsmm.com/pc_verify/install?type=upgrade&purchase_code=" . urlencode($lHaPp) . "&domain=" . urlencode($MQMJJ);
         goto eUo1k;
         EzQp7: rezoq: goto YfFhB;
         w5Y1G: $w5r4c = base64_decode($_COOKIE["lc_verified"]);
         goto sOZZq;
             deA6s: if (!(isset($_COOKIE["verify_maintenance_mode"]) && $_COOKIE["verify_maintenance_mode"] != '')) {
             goto FQtNH;
             
        }
         goto UKFW9;
         LcAwL: $MQMJJ = base_url();
         goto j1srf;
         snjE4: goto ipfmS;
         goto EzQp7;
         dxUfj: redirect(PATH . "module?error=" . $cqcJW);
         goto awyvW;
         eUo1k: $sr19N = $this->__curl($wCbGV);
         goto CaPDC;
         vj8xp: $cqcJW = $LCB3v;
         goto IYQvf;
             eS3Nc: if (!(segment(1) != '' && segment(1) != "cron")) {
             goto QjfJy;
             
        }
         goto igRjN;
         AOFGp:  goto yHvrg;
             Si7kC: if (!(isset($_COOKIE["lc_verified"]) && $_COOKIE["lc_verified"] != '')) {
             goto ICIk8;
             
        }
         goto w5Y1G;
         h4wtr: Modules::$registry[strtolower($oz81W)] = $this;
         goto n2U9a;
         aGnp_: redirect(PATH . "module?error=" . $cqcJW);
         goto fiy7l;
         m7gY6: G6RCC: goto SRKfK;
         sBAvn: $LCB3v = base64_encode($LCB3v);
         goto HOEGB;
             SRKfK: if (!(!in_array(segment(2), array("cron", "set_language")) && !in_array(segment(3), array("cron", "complete")))) {
             goto cArjg;
             
        }
         goto kCne5;
         YrdbT: g8OFd: goto LcAwL;
         INGhz: NYZyV: goto aIULL;
         fP3bG: $NjUSf =& get_instance();
         goto P7Yb3;
         Uz56g: $this->load->_autoloader($this->autoload);
         goto NolRi;
         Z0zWG: redirect(PATH . "statistics");
         goto vtb3D;
         Jmw9G: $R1bsw = json_decode($sr19N);
         goto tuGJa;
         gGOSL: QjfJy: goto bLU4U;
         NolRi: 
    }
         public function __get($oz81W) {
             return CI::$APP->{
            $oz81W
        };
         
    }
         private function __check_maintenance_mode() {
         goto ZX4Yz;
         KfWcP: $EiHk3 = $NjUSf->db->select("value");
         goto GqaMh;
         LKOtE: XkYUN: goto J06_5;
         h2AVF: $MoHPr = $this->db->get();
         goto nODyY;
         YyJW7: hBpmr: goto t3bEt;
         s7R30: return true;
         goto MyrwN;
         nODyY: $sr19N = $MoHPr->row();
         goto YnNZs;
         M6tAE: return false;
         goto mx1eh;
         SPnfH: $NjUSf->db->where("name", "is_maintenance_mode");
         goto h2AVF;
             J06_5: if ($sr19N->value) {
             goto asn8K;
             
        }
         goto M6tAE;
         sb0O0: return false;
         goto Uq85z;
         Uq85z: goto hBpmr;
         goto LKOtE;
         GqaMh: $NjUSf->db->from(OPTIONS);
         goto SPnfH;
         ZX4Yz: $NjUSf =& get_instance();
         goto KfWcP;
         mx1eh: goto DKFJS;
         goto ngz3X;
         ngz3X: asn8K: goto s7R30;
         MyrwN: DKFJS: goto YyJW7;
             YnNZs: if (!empty($sr19N)) {
             goto XkYUN;
             
        }
         goto sb0O0;
         t3bEt: 
    }
         private function __curl($wCbGV) {
         goto SMdMX;
         FuDhV: curl_setopt($zsK15, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
         goto d7SXr;
         d7SXr: $sr19N = curl_exec($zsK15);
         goto PVycI;
         Nx3pb: curl_setopt($zsK15, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
         goto tpp1f;
         HyCNB: curl_setopt($zsK15, CURLOPT_URL, $wCbGV);
         goto Nx3pb;
         WZ2gm: curl_setopt($zsK15, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
         goto FuDhV;
         zyh2N: curl_setopt($zsK15, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
         goto SxnW7;
         PVycI: curl_close($zsK15);
         goto sz6Yw;
         C23SY: curl_setopt($zsK15, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
         goto zyh2N;
         tpp1f: curl_setopt($zsK15, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
         goto Upm6Y;
         SMdMX: $zsK15 = curl_init();
         goto HyCNB;
         sz6Yw: return $sr19N;
         goto abkas;
         Upm6Y: curl_setopt($zsK15, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
         goto C23SY;
         SxnW7: curl_setopt($zsK15, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
         goto WZ2gm;
         abkas: 
    }
         private function user_allowed_controllers($ylGWj) {
         goto O1g7j;
         TN1bW: return $sr19N;
         goto mJ_0g;
         XTeHW: Af7zl: goto YRhZZ;
         YRhZZ: L3tZe: goto TN1bW;
             O1g7j: switch ($ylGWj) {
             case "supporter": $sr19N = array("faqs", "setting", "module", "api_provider", "user_block_ip", "user_logs");
             goto L3tZe;
             case "user": $sr19N = array("faqs", "users", "setting", "module", "api_provider", "category", "user_mail_logs", "user_block_ip", "user_logs");
             goto L3tZe;
             default: $sr19N = array();
             goto L3tZe;
             
        }
         goto XTeHW;
         mJ_0g: 
    }
     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a script? Just copy and paste the code into an editor and do a find/replace. Replace the code you want removed with nothing until it's all cleaned up. Shouldn't be too hard to do.